# Old task from local ICPC "Computer Class"

Tags: c++

There is a task on which I have been racking my brains for three days. The task is called Computer Class (not to be confused with other tasks from ICPC, there are many similarly named tasks).

Problem conditions: There are n * m (arranged respectively in m rows and n desks in each row) desks and students. Each student from 1 to n * m has a unique (including n * m) number. It is necessary to arrange the students so that the difference between the numbers of neighbors is more than one (those who are from above, from below and those who are from the left, the right are also neighbors).

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
forgot to mention: numbers are limited to a radius of 1≤n, m ≤50.  And the time for the program to work is half a second (and 5 seconds in real time).
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

As a result: need to write a program (preferably in the languages ​​python and C ++) an algorithm capable of accepting two numbers (n and m) to give any suitable order of the students' arrangement (if it is impossible to give such an arrangement -1).

For example:
given: 3, 4
taked:

- 1. 3. 5. 
- 4. 6. 2. 
- 7. 9. 11. 
- 10. 12. 8. 

Or given: 1, 2
taked: -1

My attempts to solve the problem:
I used the method of creating all sequences from n numbers (the method is taken from one book) and using checking functions to find the desired sequence. When I did it with a dynamic array, I succeeded, or so I thought. The program taking toooo long when it was necessary to find an answer from a sequence of 15 (3 * 5) or more numbers.

After the advice I received and much thought, I broke my head and came up with a code that would completely solve this problem.  And now how to close the question? (there is code):

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


void CClass(int n, int m);


int main(void)
{
    while (true) {
        cout << "\n   Numbers please:\n";

        int n, m;
        cin >> n;
        cin >> m;
        cout << endl;

        CClass(n, m);
    }
}


void CClass(int n, int m) {
 
    int len = n * m;

    if (len == 6) {
        cout << "1.\t3.\t5.\n4.\t6.\t2.\n";
        return ;
    }
    if (len == 9) {
        cout <<"1.\t3.\t5.\n4.\t6.\t2.\n7.\t9.\t11.\n";
        return ;
    }
    if (n < 4) {
        if (m < 4) {
            cout << "- 1\n";
            return ;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 2, k = 1; i < len; i++) {

        if (len >= j) {
            cout << j << ".\t";
            j += 2;
        }
        else {
            cout << k << ".\t";
            k += 2;
        }

        if ((i + 1) % n == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "stopped working"? There are 15! or 1307674368000 possible permutions for a 3*5 class so *brute force is not an option*

Comment: I know, the method is not very suitable for such a task, I just haven’t come up with anything.  "stopped working" - it accepts two numbers, runs them into a function and that's it, after that nothing happens, even the message about the end of the program does not come (it seems that no processes are happening, I turned off the "check" function to check it).

Comment: If no process is running then your process crashed.

Comment: I would not be surprised if there is a general pattern here for generating this in linear time.  You can probably devise a small handful of rules to do it.  Look at the example you provided.  See the pattern?  Look at the top two rows.  See how that's a solution for the `3,2` case as well?  And the next rows follow the same pattern.  What about if the rows are odd?  What about if the rows are even?  What special problems do you encounter when the solution space is narrow (e.g. 1 or 2)?  What setups create impossible configurations at each width?  This is how I would be approaching the problem.

Comment: Paddy, when I read your comment the second time, I came up with a lot of ideas. After much thought and experimentation on paper, I was able to come up with a pattern that would work without brutforce. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ДжафарEnderg if you found a good solution, you should write it as an answer and then accept it to help others.

Comment: @ДжафарEnderg Welcome to Stackoverflow. The usual approach here for "closing" a question is accepting one of the answers. As you came up with an answer by yourself, it is ok to post an answer to your own question. Also, we don't add a "(solved)" to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just first collect all even and then odd ones on the screen as an answer, and in those units of cases in which this did not work, I simply hardcode (there were only two of them: 3x3; 2x3).  You can see the code above.